# JQuery Ajax - reload Image onClick works with chrome but not with firefox nor with IE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

Ok this is very spooky....
I'm trying to reload a CAPTCHA Image which is generated on the server side and I don't want to reload the whole page for that, hence I have to use AJAX.
So what I do is to first trigger a php file on server side (with AJAX), which updates all needed stuff so I can have a new CAPTCHA Image.
Then when this is done I simply update the image src="", to load the new image from that php file.
Here the code:

---

- **File 1**

HTML:

```
<tr id="rowWithCaptcha">
                    <td><p><img id="captchaImg" src="./?<?php echo session_name() ?>=<?php echo session_id() ?>"/></p></td>
</tr>
```

JQuery-Skript:

```
$("#reloadImg").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
              url: 'getNewKCAPTCHA.php',
              cache: false,
              type: 'POST',  
              async: false,
              success: function(){
                 $("#captchaImg").attr("src","http://localhost/Captcha2/TestPages/TestPage3Q/getNewKCAPTCHA.php?");
              }
           });
        });
```

---

- **File two:**

PHP:
kcaptcha.php is where all the captcha magic happends :)
so if you just open this php file in your browser, you'll get the captcha image itself.
And if you reload the page the image changes every time.....

```
    <?php include('kcaptcha.php'); session_start(); $captcha = new KCAPTCHA(); $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] = $captcha-getKeyString(); echo TRUE; ?>
```

---

So the weird thing now is that this whole thing (AJAX call and update of picture) is working just fine with the new chrome browser, but when I try it with FFOX or IE it works only one time and any further click doesnt change anything.....I think it has something to do with the JQuery part, but I just cant get it to work :///

Every help is appreciated!!!
Thanx in advance!

Comment: You do know you can just change the src attribute without any ajax, as you're not using the data returned in that ajax call anyway? Setting the image source to a PHP file, and doing ajax without using the returned data makes me think you don't really get the concept ?

Comment: Also consider cache problems: if you assign the same SRC once and once again, maybe the browser is using cached version of the content. Consider adding something varying parameter, like `var d = new Date (); $("#captchaImg").attr ("src", "http://localhost/Captcha2/TestPages/TestPage3Q/getNewKCAPTCHA.php?r=" + d.getTime ());`

Comment: @adeneo: I dont know maybe I did not get the concept, but I need to make sure that the image from the php file is a new one. Hende I need to trigger it with ajax, so I figured.....maybe you could contribute a solution without ajax??? that would be very appreciated.....cause after all I'm still in the learning process here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

```
url: 'getNewKCAPTCHA.php',
```

and

```
http://localhost/Captcha2/TestPages/TestPage3Q/getNewKCAPTCHA.php?
```

are actually the same script, there is no need to call them twice.

Consider this simple method (it's working method I use in real projects):

```
$("#reloadImg").click(function(){
    var d = new Date ();
    var captcha = "http://localhost/Captcha2/TestPages/TestPage3Q/getNewKCAPTCHA.php?r=" + d.getTime ();
    $("#captchaImg").attr ("src", captcha);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hGfgn/

Regards

Comment: Very informative, thanx!! **This was the cure for my problem :)**  I just did't know any other way of calling the php file, then trough AJAX, but thanx to you now I know how I can do it otherwise!!!! Big Cheers  :)

Answer (score 0):

this might be corellating to the HTML5 support. i had the same problem not long ago and it seems that neither FF nor IE support

```
$('whatever').click(function(){});
```

but it could work if you call it with onclick="function()" in the html-tag, but i do not know if it works

Comment: Are you saying IE and FF does not support the standard jQuery click function ?

Comment: Ok I'm diffidently gone take a look at that too, but so far I have been using this  $('whatever').click(function(){}); quite often in my projekt and never ran into problems.

Comment: i am not sure to when this error occurs but it seems quite clear that at least in some cases FF and IE will not support the jQuery Click function. pleas dont ask why, at least not me. but it can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of editing src attributes.
I would usually remove the image (or replace with a loading image) and then append the new image (and remove the loading image). The code below should remove the image and append a new image - I missed out all of the buffering image replacement stuff

```
 $("#reloadImg").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                  url: 'getNewKCAPTCHA.php',
                  cache: false,
                  type: 'POST',  
                  async: false,
                  success: function(){
                     $("#captchaImg").remove();
                     $("#rowWithCaptcha td p").append('<img id="captchaImg" src="http://localhost/Captcha2/TestPages/TestPage3Q/getNewKCAPTCHA.php?" />');

                  }
               });
            });
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yeah....had the same Idea and trying it I still did end up with the same problem that FFOX AND IE do it only one time and chrome does works.....  :/

Comment: have you done as others suggest and add a time based variable onto the end of the file to make sure that the image is not caching?